# Use a checkbox into the table for union de register and make a parent for this union (Spring - JPA)

Tags: jquery, jsp, checkbox, spring-data-jpa, spring-annotations

i have a problem, in my work ask me if is posible to make a table with 6 columns and the last two columns use for checkbox and radiobutton. When you select a group to checkbox inside for this select group you need to seleect a father using tha radiobutton and in the DB you need to save this union and the parent. Now you can select one register for parent and child. Then if you don't finished, you can reload this page and see the other registers with out mark for make the same action to begining.

i read about checkbox multiples but nothing about union the group to checkbox and make a parent into this group, and then show the checkbox without checked

Thanks for the help and sorry for my english.